# Not all gameobjects with the same script attached are respawning

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm working on a Unity2D platformer which has blocks that break/fall when the player jumps onto them. Once the player makes contact, there is a short delay, then the block begins to slide down and shortly disappears (using SetActive(false)). If the player dies, then all "falling" blocks should respawn and return to their original positions.

I've made a level where there are two of these blocks (two completely independent gameobjects), but the problem is that when the player breaks both and then dies, when the player respawns **only one** of the two blocks respawns to its original position. (The other is never to be seen again.)

I think this may have something to do with how they are both attached to the same script. However I don't see how because a different gameobject is still specified in each instance of the script for each block.

Here's the code for the script attached to the block gameobjects (called breakingBlock).

```
public class BreakingBlock : MonoBehaviour
{
    Collider2D boxCollider;

    public GameObject slidingBlock;
    public PlayerController player;

    public float delay;
    public float X;
    public float startY;
    public float endY;
    public float speed;

    void Start() // Initialises the position of the blocks
    {
        boxCollider = GetComponent<Collider2D>();
        boxCollider.enabled = true;
        slidingBlock.transform.position = new Vector2(X, startY);
        player = FindObjectOfType<PlayerController>();
    }


    void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D collision) 
        // Starts sliding coroutine when touched by player
    {
        StartCoroutine(Slide(slidingBlock, new Vector2(X, startY), new Vector2(X, endY), delay, speed));
    }

    public IEnumerator Slide(GameObject slidingBlock, Vector2 start, Vector2 end, float delay, float speed)
    {
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(delay);

        while (slidingBlock.transform.position.y != end.y)
        {
            // Move towards end position over duration given
            slidingBlock.transform.position = Vector2.MoveTowards(slidingBlock.transform.position, end, speed * Time.deltaTime);
            yield return new WaitForEndOfFrame();
        }

        boxCollider.enabled = false;
        slidingBlock.SetActive(false);
    }


    public void ResetSlidingBlock() // Called by another script when player dies
    {
        Debug.Log("Reset block");
        slidingBlock.transform.position = new Vector2(X, startY);
        slidingBlock.SetActive(true);
        boxCollider.enabled = true;
    }
}
```

This is the part of the other script that calls ResetSlidingBlock from the above script breakingBlock when the player dies.

```
void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D collision)
{
    if (collision.name == "Player")
    {
        levelManager.RespawnPlayer();
        breakingBlock.ResetSlidingBlock();
    }
}
```

Why is it that only one of the blocks is respawning when separate gameobjects are specified in the separate scripts on completely distinct gameobjects?

Comment: You are only resetting "breakingBlock" instance with breakingBlock.ResetSlidingBlock();. If you want to reset more blocks, you need to refer to each of the instances to reset each one of them. As far as I can guess "public GameObject slidingBlock;" can be a list of all the blocks, (public GameObject[] slidingBlock;) so that you can then access and reset each of the blocks

Answer (score 1):

You have a public GameObject where only one object is assigned. Doesn't matter how many objects you assign this script to, only that GameObject that you refer to will be reset. If you have X number of GameObjects that you want to follow the same properties, you can:

1. Make a prefab and access the children using transform.getchild() or tags - assign them to GameObjects
   ex:

   `GameObject objs[];
   for(int i=0;i<How many u want;i++)
   {
   objs[i]=GameObject.Find("ParentObj").transform.GetChild(i);
   //something similar to this
   }`
2. Or Simply Make public references and assign them manually.

Ex:

```
public GameObject slideblock1;
public GameObject slideblock2;
```

etc.

Comment: How would #2 work when one specific gameobject needs to be referred to in the rest of the script? If there are several gameobjects, then what would go in place of "slidingBlock" in my code above?

Comment: you can put all these gameobjects in a list/array and use a loop. You can use specific checks like gameObject.active or index value so that the reset wont be applied to all of them